# In VIM, How to avoid hit-enter prompts after executing long command?

Tags: vim

I'm writing my vimrc file and do some `onoremap` like this:

```
onoremap i@ :<c-u>execute "normal! /\\w\\+@\\w\\+\\.[0-9a-zA-Z.]\\+\r:nohlsearch\rvf@h"<CR>
```

For this one, I map the `i@` to do some operation on "the username of the next email-like string". It works fine in vim window that is large enough. However, when I test it on a relatively small vim window, for example, hit `ci@` to quickly change the username of the next email-like string, this execution needs a hit-enter to go on before I can really "change". This is kind of awful since I may frequently do vim things in really small windows.

I believe the hit-enter prompt here was caused by the too long message when executing the search command. I have googled for solution, and I know I can set `shortmess` flag in vim to make message shorter or increase the height of command line display. But I think these solutions are not ***essence***.

Besides, I don't want to omit the external command line output. **Is there some way to totally avoid hit-enter prompts that are caused only by "not enough message space"?**

Or is there some way I can change in my `onoremap` code to meet this need?

Thanks a lot :)

(Google solution: [Avoiding the "Hit ENTER to continue" prompts](https://vim.fandom.com/wiki/Avoiding_the_%22Hit_ENTER_to_continue%22_prompts))

**Edit: I said "vim window", but actually the problem was not prompted due to a small "window in vim", but "vim in a small terminal display". If you split a small vim window but still with a long message bar, the hit-enter prompt won't occur.**

Comment: Read `:help hit-enter`

Comment: I have read `:help hit-enter` but I couldn't find a solution to op's question that doesn't rely on `shortmess`. Could you elaborate @Matt?

Comment: @jpnadas Basically it says that there's no general way to disable hit-enter prompts (unlike more-prompts). Therefore, one should simply reduce the number of messages. Something like `onoremap <silent>@i :<C-U>silent execute ...`

Comment: I was trying to make silent work for a while, but wasn't quite getting the syntax. Thanks for that @Matt.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is there some way to totally avoid hit-enter prompts that are caused only by "not enough message space"?

No. Only "more prompts" can be fully disabled. See `:help hit-enter`.

> I believe the hit-enter prompt here was caused by the too long message when executing the search command.

I guess, not the length but the number of messages: one message for echoing the mapping, and another for `/` output.

Try to use `silent` like this:

```
onoremap <silent>i@ :<c-u>silent! execute ...
```

The first `<silent>` suppresses "echo", the second one suppresses the command's output.

Comment: Thanks for help. I almost believe you are right, but it still doesn't work. Maybe you can use a really small terminal to give it a try? I'm not quite sure.

Comment: It does help in some way.
`onoremap <silent>test :<c-u>silent execute "normal! :set number\r:set nonumber\r"<CR>` no prompt, while `onoremap test :<c-u>execute "normal! :set number\r:set nonumber\r"<CR>` has prompt. But for my original question's example, it doesn't work.

Comment: @PorcupineAndrew You're constantly overusing execute / normal / : / \r. Consider simply `onoremap test :<c-u>set number \| set nonumber<cr>`

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'm new to vim and just met onoremap recently. By the way, does `onoremap <silent>i@ :<c-u>silent execute "normal! /\\w\\+@\\w\\+\\.[0-9a-zA-Z.]\\+\r:nohlsearch\rvf@h"<CR>` have hit-enter prompt in your terminal?

Comment: @PorcupineAndrew Nope, unless it's really small and the pattern is not found - in this case `/` prints an error message. BTW. error messages could be suppressed with `silent!`

Comment: Thanks. You're right. My problem is in somewhere else. After I commented the other lines in my vimrc file, the hit-enter prompt never happens. **`Silent` really works.** Thank you very much.
(also thank @jpnadas)